# Does Thunderbolt 3 speed up access to non-Thunderbolt drives?

Tags: external-hard-drive, thunderbolt

I am about to buy a new laptop and am considering one with a Thunderbolt 3 port - if it would speed up my backups to external drive.

Obviously, if the external drive is al TB 3, that would be optimal.

What if it is not? Are there are speed gains from the TB3 laptop to the non=TB external drive?

---

[Update]  I only leaned about TB today, when looking at laptops.

A quick search shows that some drives as described as [Thunderbird 3 drive](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=thunderbird+external+drive), which might indicate some extra bit-banging hardware to facilitate faster transfer.

Otherwise it's just a question of "can a normal externa harddrive send data faster than a PC's laptop can receive it"? If so, adding a faster TB port the laptop will speed up transfer, otherwise, it will not (but adding TB3 on both ends will).

Can anyone explain the downvote? (oh, yeah, S.E ;-)

Comment: What exactly is a non-Thunderbolt 3 drive?

Comment: An old external hard-drive that I have lying around (+1). Please, see update to question

Comment: You have to be more specific.  A USB external drive obviously cannot take advantage of Thunderbolt 3 speeds since the controller of the drive is USB not Thunderbolt 3

Comment: A mechanical drive connected to a Thunderbolt 3 drive will be limited by the mechanical drive.  As stated earlier any drive that isn’t directly Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 3 cannot by the nature of that connection take advantage of thunderbolt 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't.

For comparison let's have USB 2.0, USB 3.0 and a Thunderbolt 3 hard drives

- Connection over USB 2.0 tops out at 480 Mb per second
- Connection over USB 3.1 has a data signaling rate of up to 10 Gb per second
- Connection over Thunderbolt 3 tops out at 40 Gbps

These results are guaranteed only when using the same type of serial bus for connection (e.g. USB 3.1 -> USB 3.1)

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess that I could just buy a new TB3 drive housing for my existing 12tB backup drive

Comment: You're welcome 